# OnSelectedIndexChanged Not Firing in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

Gridview Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvVessel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
     EmptyDataText="No Vessels found." OnRowCommand="gvVessel_RowCommand"      
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVessel_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="VesselID" >
<asp:/GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvVessel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt16(gvVessel.SelectedDataKey.Value);
    Cache["index"] = index;

    Response.Redirect("VesselDraft.aspx");
}
```

Why isn't the event firing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: This answer may be hard to answer unless you post the rest of your GV code

Comment: </GridView> should be : </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Pink see the above Comment.. Your Grid View ending server tag might be an issue..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView OnSelectedIndexChanged event not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166568/gridview-onselectedindexchanged-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the SO questions
[GridView OnSelectedIndexChanged event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166568/gridview-onselectedindexchanged-event-not-firing)
[Gridview selectedindex changed not firing on first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513185/gridview-selectedindex-changed-not-firing-on-first-click)

[gridview SelectedIndexChanged Event is not firing.I am using asp.net 4.0 .By the way rowdatabound event is firing perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149383/gridview-selectedindexchanged-event-is-not-firing-i-am-using-asp-net-4-0-by-the)

If you are just clicking on the row in the `GridView`, that will not fire the event.  You have to have some kind of button in the row to click on, which will fire the `RowCommand` event, as well as the `SelectedIndexChanged` event (if the row you click is not already selected, of course).  It's not exactly like the Windows Forms DataGridView =)

The easiest way to get the event to fire, is to add this attribute to your `GridView` markup:

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
```

This creates a "Select" `LinkButton`, which will fire the `Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged2` event in your code-behind when you click it.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, this is where you need to add that attribute:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" 
  Width="930px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  
  onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged2"
  AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" >
```

Comment: Can we change the Text of AutoGenerateSelectButton?? Select to someOther Text??

Comment: Without AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" and any button on that Row is'it possible to fire that event?

Comment: Yes you can give any name.

Comment: you can have template field and in that you can have a button or link or imagebutton etc and from there too you can fire the same event

Comment: Please set property Autopostback ="true" of gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Please set property

```
AutoPostback ="true" for GridView.
```

Thanks,
Hitesh